# Remove custom category attribute from observer

Tags: magento-1.9, category-tree, category-attribute

I m removing custom category attribute from the form for second level category.

I m using magento observer for it and the event is `adminhtml_catalog_category_edit_prepare_form`

I m using below code to remove but it does'n work.

```
public function removeAttribute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $form = $observer->getForm();

                if (Mage::registry('current_category')->getLevel() == 2) {

                    $form->removeField('menu_type');
                }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Try to debug: 1) is the observer actually triggered? 2) is `removeField()` called? 3) Does the form have a field `menu_type` at this point?

Comment: Yes everything is setup correctly and present.